# Horizontal to off-canvas nav with splash screen, absolute positioning conflicts

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I'm working on the same site from a previous question (and I'm a CSS3 noob).  The site I'm working on has a horizontal navigation menu that switches to an off canvas menu.  I'm turning classes on and off with jQuery and it's looking pretty good.  The html is divided into two divs, a #drawer and a #site-canvas.
Simplified, the html looks something like this

```
<body>
<nav id="drawer">
//ul menu stuff
</nav>
<div id="site-canvas">
   <header> // header for mobile version </header>
   <div class="splash">//Splash Screen<div>
   <div id="site-content">//Lorem Ipsum<div>
</div> <!--End #site-canvas-->
</body>
```

It's going to feature a splash screen with an image that will take up 100% of the viewport and stay centered.

```
/* Splash page */
.splash {
    background: url('//image') center center;
     background-size: cover;
     min-height: 100%;
 }
```

So far so good, but in the desktop styles (1000px+ width) we now have a conflict with the nav div being outside the site canvas is causing it to be fixed with separate a scroll bar (also the splash screen arrow is now fixed too and the bottom of the image isn't at the bottom of the viewport). The mobile version doesn't have these problems.
http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/pJVKmv 
[image: Fixed problem]

I can fix the issues above with absolute positioning, but then I lose natural document flow and the page context flows over the screen.

```
.splash {
    background: url('//someimage.jpg') center center;
     background-size: cover;
     min-height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     position:absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 0;
}
```

[image: Absolute positioning problem]
http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/oXdMBy

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm so lost.

Comment: I think adding `position:relative` to your `splash` div should fix your arrow issue in the first codepen

Comment: Is this [Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwGBob) close to what you are looking for?

Comment: @zgood Yeah! Thank you! I came up with my own solution but that used two navs (one in and one out of the site canvas) and turning hiding / displaying them with media queries. Your solution looks really good :D I just need to modify the jQuery animate function's argument to #site-canvas if the header is visible and body if it's not. You should put your fiddle in an answer with explanations so I can give you the proper reputation award :D

Comment: No prob bob. I posted an answer which explains what the hell I did. Let me know if you need help with your jQuery. Good luck!

Comment: @zgood Thank you, I think I've got the jQuery. Here:   `$("#downSplashArrow").click(function(event) {      event.preventDefault();    if ($('header').is(":visible")) {       $('#site-canvas').animate({ scrollTop: $("#page-content").offset().top }, 1000); } else {          $('body').animate({           scrollTop: $("#page-content").offset().top        }, 1000);  }  }); ` Now if I could figure out how to make the header bar fixed in the mobile styles, that would be pretty cool.  But you've already done a lot for me so I couldn't ask for more :)

Comment: If you create a new question with an updated CodePen I will give it the ol' look-see. Just post a link to the new question in these comments and I'll check it out.

Comment: @zgood Here it is, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352821/making-a-header-menu-bar-for-an-off-canvas-navigation-menu-fixed but if it's too much trouble don't worry about it.  Again, I can't thank you enough for helping me.  This is the first time I've made a responsive site like this and I'm learning so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have came up with a solution [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwGBob).

To fix the arrow problem I added `position:relative;` to the `splash` div to make the arrow, which is `position:absolute;` anchor itself to this div, instead of the browser window.

To fix the `nav` issue I changed its positioning to `fixed`, and then removed `overflow:hidden;` from `body, html` and removed `overflow-y: scroll;` from `#site-canvas` tag.

This makes the `nav` fixed. which I think is the intended goal, and allows the the rest of the document flow naturally by removing the overflow style properties of the wrapping elements.